# Can I make an Spinner that shows the info but doesn't allows to select it?

Tags: android

I'm making this android app. The idea is that when the user selects a name it display the info as a drop down. For this effect I have used android documentation on spinners. The problem radicates in that it allows the user to select one of the items in the list (after all that is what Spinner does):

Is there a way I can modify the spinner, si it just show the info without the possibility of this being selected by the user?

this is the code of the spinner:

```
<Spinner
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:background="@color/Artes"
/>
```

String Array

```
    <string-array name="names">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Work</item>
    <item>Other</item>
    <item>HCustom</item>
    </string-array>
```

Spinner Adapter

```
Spinner arquitecturaNacional = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>   
(NacionalInicial.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
her getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names));
  myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    arquitecturaNacional.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can override the `OnItemSelected` event of the spinner.

Lets suppose the item you are setting as default selected is the `index = 1`, you can override this method like the following:

```
//manage automatic set of the selection
bool isAutomaticSelected = false;
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    //manage the bool
    if(isAutomaticSelected){ 
      isAutomaticSelected = false;
    }
    else{
      mySpinner.setSelection(1); //or any index u want
      isAutomaticSelected = true;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    if(isAutomaticSelected){ 
      isAutomaticSelected = false;
    }
    else{
      mySpinner.setSelection(1); //or any index u want
      isAutomaticSelected = true;
    }
  }

});
```

In this way any time an user select an item from the dropdown view or select anything,

I set the boolean because elseway it would have resulted in an infinite loop.

hope this helps

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Im working with it,  but I got this: setOnItemSelectedListener, AdapterView, selectedItemView, parentView and setSelection as "cannot resolve symbol". And one question does mySpinner refers to the id of the spinner in the .xml file or the spinner value declared in the java file? thanks

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are asking.. about the mySpinner is obv the object in java file. this object must be istantiated with the ref to the id in xml file, like any other object :)